# Автоматизация установки нужного положения монитора и частоты обновления после перезагрузки ОС Windows 10

Tags: python, gui, windows-10, скрипт, автоматизация

Очень уж надоело вручную менять положение и герцовку мониторов в системе с более,чем одним монитором каждый раз после перезагрузки ОС, поэтому решил написать данный код. На данный момент он умеет устанавливать выбранному монитору определённое разрешение и частоту обновления, после чего успешно сохраняет эти данные в текстовый файл после согласия пользователя. Для каждого монитора можно задать отдельные значения, они все хранятся в одном файле и новая информация по уже записанному в файл монитору перезаписывает старую, не затрагивая остальную. Я не профессиональный программист, в подобном коде я увидел возможность научиться чему-то новому. Но на данный момент моих знаний не хватает для дополнения функционала. Как написано в шапке, этот код должен автоматизировать изменение частоты обновления и положения монитора. Часть функционала уже есть. Теперь нужно как-то сделать возможность выбрать положение монитора, которое будет записано в тот же самый файл (У меня, например, два монитора. Первый монитор находится над вторым. В системе это так и обозначено. Но после перезагрузки или релогина мониторы меняют свою последовательность так, что первый находится слева от второго). После чего, как я предполагаю, нужно будет написать отдельное приложение, которое будет брать все данные из этого текстового файла, применяя эти настройки. Ну и, соответственно, это самое второе приложение уже будет поставлено в автозагрузку Windows, чтобы при запуске всё выставлялось как указано в файле.
Если у Вас есть какие-либо идеи, вы знаете как можно дополнить функционал, следуя из описания или вы знаете, как можно улучшить код, то напишите, пожалуйста.
Вот сам код:

```py
import os
import win32api
import win32con
import questionary
 
class MonitorInfo:
    def __init__(self, name, device, width, height):
        self.name = name
        self.device = device
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
 
def clear_screen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
 
def get_monitors():
    monitors = []
    device = win32api.EnumDisplayDevices(None, 0)
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            device_name = device.DeviceName
            if device_name:
                mode = win32api.EnumDisplaySettings(device.DeviceName, win32con.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS)
                monitors.append(MonitorInfo(device_name, device.DeviceName, mode.PelsWidth, mode.PelsHeight))
            i += 1
            device = win32api.EnumDisplayDevices(None, i)
        except:
            break
    return monitors
 
def get_supported_resolutions(monitor_device):
    resolutions = {}
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            mode = win32api.EnumDisplaySettings(monitor_device, i)
            resolution = (mode.PelsWidth, mode.PelsHeight)
            frequency = mode.DisplayFrequency
 
            # Проверяем, что разрешение поддерживается монитором
            if resolution[0] > 0 and resolution[1] > 0:
                if resolution in resolutions:
                    resolutions[resolution].add(frequency)
                else:
                    resolutions[resolution] = {frequency}
            i += 1
        except:
            break
    return resolutions
 
def get_closest_resolution(target_width, target_height, target_frequency, monitor_width, monitor_height, resolutions):
    min_distance = float('inf')
    closest_resolution = None
 
    for resolution, frequencies in resolutions.items():
        width, height = resolution
        for frequency in frequencies:
            distance = abs(width - target_width) + abs(height - target_height) + abs(frequency - target_frequency)
 
            # Учитываем только те разрешения, которые имеют близкое соотношение сторон к монитору
            if abs(width / height - monitor_width / monitor_height) < 0.1:
                if distance < min_distance:
                    min_distance = distance
                    closest_resolution = resolution, frequency
 
    return closest_resolution
 
def change_screen_resolution(width, height, frequency, monitor_device):
    devmode = win32api.EnumDisplaySettings(monitor_device, win32con.ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS)
    devmode.PelsWidth = width
    devmode.PelsHeight = height
    devmode.DisplayFrequency = frequency
    win32api.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(monitor_device, devmode)
 
def save_resolution_info(selected_monitor, width, height, frequency):
    monitor_info = {
        "Монитор": selected_monitor.name,
        "Разрешение": f"{width}x{height}",
        "Частота обновления": f"{frequency}Hz"
    }
    
    updated_info = False
    with open("monitors.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            if lines[i].startswith("Монитор:") and selected_monitor.name in lines[i]:
                updated_info = True
                lines[i:i+4] = [f"{key}: {value}\n" for key, value in monitor_info.items()]
                break
    
    if not updated_info:
        with open("monitors.txt", "a") as file:
            for key, value in monitor_info.items():
                file.write(f"{key}: {value}\n")
            file.write("\n")
    else:
        with open("monitors.txt", "w") as file:
            file.writelines(lines)
 
def select_resolution(selected_monitor):
    clear_screen()
    print(f"Выбранный монитор: {selected_monitor.name}\n")
 
    supported_resolutions = get_supported_resolutions(selected_monitor.device)
    resolutions_choices = [
        f"{resolution[0]}x{resolution[1]}"
        for resolution in sorted(supported_resolutions.keys(), key=lambda x: x[0] * x[1], reverse=True)
    ]
    resolutions_choices.append("Назад")
    selected_resolution_str = questionary.select("Выберите разрешение:", choices=resolutions_choices).ask()
 
    if selected_resolution_str == "Назад":
        return
 
    width, height = map(int, selected_resolution_str.split("x"))
 
    # Проверяем, что выбранное разрешение является корректным
    if (width, height) not in supported_resolutions:
        (width, height), _ = get_closest_resolution(width, height, 60, selected_monitor.width, selected_monitor.height, supported_resolutions)
        print(f"Выбранное разрешение некорректно и будет заменено на ближайшее корректное: {width}x{height}")
 
    clear_screen()
    print(f"Выбранный монитор: {selected_monitor.name}")
    print(f"Выбранное разрешение: {width}x{height}\n")
 
    select_frequency(selected_monitor, width, height)
 
def select_frequency(selected_monitor, width, height):
    supported_resolutions = get_supported_resolutions(selected_monitor.device)
    supported_frequencies = supported_resolutions[(width, height)]
 
    frequencies_choices = sorted(list(supported_frequencies), reverse=True)
    frequencies_choices.append("Назад")
    selected_frequency_str = questionary.select("Выберите частоту обновления:", choices=[str(freq) for freq in frequencies_choices]).ask()
 
    if selected_frequency_str == "Назад":
        return
 
    frequency = int(selected_frequency_str)
 
    clear_screen()
    print(f"Выбранный монитор: {selected_monitor.name}")
    print(f"Выбранное разрешение: {width}x{height}")
    print(f"Выбранная частота обновления: {frequency}Hz\n\n")
 
    change_screen_resolution(width, height, frequency, selected_monitor.device)
 
    save_option = questionary.confirm("Сохранить информацию об измененных настройках?").ask()
 
    if save_option:
        save_resolution_info(selected_monitor, width, height, frequency)
 
    input("Для продолжения нажмите Enter...")
    select_resolution(selected_monitor)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        clear_screen()
        monitors = get_monitors()
        monitor_choices = [f"{monitor.name} ({monitor.width}x{monitor.height})" for monitor in monitors]
        monitor_choices.append("Выход")
        selected_monitor_str = questionary.select("Выберите монитор:", choices=monitor_choices).ask()
 
        if selected_monitor_str == "Выход":
            break
 
        selected_monitor_index = monitor_choices.index(selected_monitor_str)
        selected_monitor = monitors[selected_monitor_index]
 
        select_resolution(selected_monitor)
```